# protobuf-net: Encoding for DateTime

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm using Python protobuf library to read message sent by a .Net application that use protobuf-net.
The .Net app sends DateTime. The datetime encoding does not seems trivial and I don't know how to parse it.
Anybody know the formatting of the DateTime in the protobuf-net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was doing it all over again, I would have done it much simpler - I
might still add an option to make it simpler! but:

[bcl.proto](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/Tools/bcl.proto)

Basically, it chooses the correct scale to guarantee the value. So you just need to do some multiplication of the `.value` based on the `.scale`.

Comment: May I suggest to use the same format as HTTP protocol? LIke RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123

Comment: @efficks why would we do that? HTTP is a text protocol... protobuf: isn't. Frankly, "[interval] in [epoch]" is more common - unix timestamp or millisecond equivalent, for example.

Comment: Because your library need to be compatible with other language and librairies. When somebody check this in the future, if your library is deprecated, he still need to be able to read the data. Using the epoch is nice too, but which one. UNIX? You are on Windows in .net. In .net epoch is 0001-01-01T00:00:00. So which one to use? With a string, you are sure. The other option is stop supporting datetime at all and let the user encode it as it's need and document like he want. Like that, nobody will need to open source code in the protobuf library to understand what it does.

Comment: @efficks unix time is pretty standard; I don't see that as a concern. Untimately, though: protobuf (the spec, not protobuf-net) *doesn't have* a predefined date/time representation, so *everyone* has to come up with something. Unix time is a pretty common choice, but if you want control you're welcome to do what many other protobuf users need to do and write a member in whatever type and meaning that you choose - some have a `string TheTime` or `long TheTime`, etc